# Prove $P(B|A) \le P(\bar{A} \cup B)$ provided $P(A) > 0$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

In a philosophy paper I've encountered the claim that for any probability measure $P$ alongside events $A$ and $B$ it follows that  $P(B|A) \le P(\bar{A} \cup B)$ provided $P(A) > 0$. I'm wondering if anyone might help me to see how to prove this claim. So far I've derived the following

$\begin{align*}
   P(\bar{A} \cup B)
   &= P(\bar{A}) + P(B) - P(\bar{A} \cap B)\\
   &= 1 - P(A) + P(B) - P(\bar{A}|B) P(B)\\
   &= 1 - P(A) + (1 - P(\bar{A}|B)) P(B)\\
   &= 1 - P(A) + P(A|B)P(B)\\
   &= 1 - P(A) + P(B|A)P(A)\\
   &= 1 - P(A)(1 - P(B|A))\\
\end{align*}$

but I'm not seeing how to manipulate this further to get the inequality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that

\begin{align*}
   P(\bar{A} \cup B)
   &= 1 - P(A)(1 - P(B|A))
   \\
   &\geq 1- 1(1 - P(B|A))
\\
   &= 1- 1 + P(B|A)
\\
   &= P(B|A)
\end{align*}